# Is there any way to force customer to change password in NopCommerce

Tags: model-view-controller, passwords, nopcommerce

We had moved one of our store from PrestaShop to nopCommerce. During the migration, we lost all registered customer's passwords because of password encryption policy.

We have migrated all customers and given them a default password. We were thinking if there is a way to force each customer to change the password on first-time login.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is implemented in nopCommerce 3.90 ([issue-2009](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues/2009)), you can manage security rules in Configuration -> Settings -> Customer Settings.

By ticking the "Enable password lifetime" checkbox in Customer -> Customer roles in corresponding customer role editing page, and setting up old date to all passwords, you will bind users to change the password.